# How can I upsert multiple objects with MongoDB & Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Let's say I have an array of Movie genres like so:

```
[ 
    { id: 28, name: 'Action' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Adventure' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Animation' },
    { id: 35, name: 'Comedy' },
    { id: 80, name: 'Crime' },
    { id: 99, name: 'Documentary' },
    { id: 18, name: 'Drama' },
    { id: 10751, name: 'Family' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Fantasy' },
    { id: 10769, name: 'Foreign' },
    { id: 36, name: 'History' },
    { id: 27, name: 'Horror' },
    { id: 10402, name: 'Music' },
    { id: 9648, name: 'Mystery' },
    { id: 10749, name: 'Romance' },
    { id: 878, name: 'Science Fiction' },
    { id: 10770, name: 'TV Movie' },
    { id: 53, name: 'Thriller' },
    { id: 10752, name: 'War' },
    { id: 37, name: 'Western' }
]
```

and I have a connection to a MongoDB (v3.2) instance: `db`, and I'm using the standard mongodb Node.js driver (`const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient`).

What I want to be able to do is one bulk upsert operation onto a collection, say `genres`, where the `_id` field maps to the `id` field of our genre objects.

Now, I know I could loop through each item in the array, and do a simple upsert:

```
for (let i = 0; i < genres.length; i++) {
  await db.collection('genres').update(
    { _id: genres[i].id },
    genres[i],
    { upsert: true }
  );
}
```

But this feels *wasteful* and wrong.

Is there an easier way to do what should be a relatively simple task?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the **[`bulkWrite`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite)** API to carry out the updates:

```
var bulkUpdateOps = genres.map(function(doc) {
    return {
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc.id },
            "update": { "$set": { "name": doc.name } },
            "upsert": true
        }
    };
});

db.collection('genres').bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps, function(err, r) {
    // do something with result
})
```

---

If you're dealing with larger arrays i.e. > 1000 then consider sending the writes to the server in batches of 500 which gives you a better performance as you are not sending every request to the server, just once in every 500 requests:

```
var bulkUpdateOps = [],
    counter = 0;

genres.forEach(function(doc) {
    bulkUpdateOps.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc.id },
            "update": { "$set": { "name": doc.name } },
            "upsert": true
        }
    });
    counter++;

    if (counter % 500 == 0) {
        db.collection('genres').bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps, function(err, r) {
            // do something with result
        });
        bulkUpdateOps = [];
    }
})

if (counter % 500 != 0) {
    db.collection('genres').bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps, function(err, r) {
        // do something with the result
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Given the small number of rows, I think I'm going to go with the small example I gave above. It's a shame that this is so verbose.

Comment: @chridam: why do you `bulkWrite()` every 500 douments? Couldn't you simply write all array at once? Is there some performance penalty?

Comment: @MarcoS Good question, for bulk operations MongoDB imposes a default internal [limit](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Write-Command-Operation-Limit-Size) of 1000 operations per batch and the choice of 500 documents is arbitrary, i.e. for larger operation in the magnitude of > 1000 documents. So for the above case yes, one could just write all the array at once as this is small but the 500 choice was for larger arrays.

Comment: can I directly set doc instead of doc.name, any performance issue will get?

Answer (score 2):

I would try:

```
db.collection('genres').update(genres, {upsert: true, multi: true});
```

*Note: untested code...*

**UPDATE**: to remap `id` field to `_id`:

```
var _genres = genres.map(function(genre) {
   return { _id: genre.id, name: genre.name };
});

db.collection('genres').update(_genres, {upsert: true, multi: true});
```

Comment: How would this map `_id` to `id` though?

Comment: Can't you map your genres array 'id' fields to '_id' ? I'm adding some sample code to my answer to show how to do it...

Comment: Yes... :-) Probably sleeker solutions exist, but... :-)

Comment: Thanks, I had the same approach to mapping but the update operation fails, complaining about the first two params. If we pass _genres first, we have a `MongoError: wrong type for 'q' field, expected object, found q: `, and if we pass in `{}` to first param, we get `MongoError: wrong type for 'u' field, expected object, found u: `. Any ideas?

Comment: No, sorry... I would try with *mongodb bulk write* (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/)