# mongoDB updateMany with upsert true and $in in where condition

Tags: mongodb

How to insert many records if where condition does not meet with upsert true, for example consider below query,

```
db.getCollection('Llog').updateMany(
{"macID" : {$in : [1,2]}}, 
{$push : { "logDetails" : { $each : [{ wk: 15, score: 15 }] }}}, 
{upsert : true}
)
```

in my where condition i use "$in" [1,2], if there is record for macID : 1 then i should update the record with "logDetails", if i do not find record for macID : 2 then i need to insert record. If i find both records exist then update both Or if i find both records not exist then insert.

For the above code, it inserts record as below, if both are not exist

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f18e68c19f798cffa406a8"),
    "logDetails" : [ 
        {
            "wk" : 15,
            "score" : 15
        }
    ]
}
```

For example, if macId : 1 is available then i do the 1st set of updateMany code, then it should update macID : 1 and insert macID : 2, but it does not insert macID : 2 but it updates macID : 1.

Comment: You cannot do that at present. Instead of `.updateMany()` you an issue two operations to `.bulkWrite()` with `"upsert"` set to `true` on each. The current DSL has no way to determine which of `1` or `2` is presently being operated on as an "upsert". There's probably a JIRA on it but it just escapes me at the moment to find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`{"macID" : {$in : [1,2]}}` do not means that you are searching a two documents (with `"macID" : 1` and `"macID" : 2`), it means that you are searching any documents which have `macID` eaqual to `1` or `2`.

So `upsert: true` tells to MongoDB to create only one document (not two).

You must provide the multiple update requests (use [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) with `updateOne` not `updateMany`).

Comment: Okay, how can we resolve this? Is there any other way?

Comment: @user use `bulkWrite` with `updateOne` (I updated my answer)

Comment: Anyone looking for the implementation, [check this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36774951/9212590)